# How to aggregate categorical data where the unique id has multiple rows with different values for another column?

Tags: python

I need to aggregate data with the same id's into one row, but save the different Code's into different columns.

I look into this post: [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe), but this post does not answer my question.

For example: the input dataframe can be:

```
d = {'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'Code': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df1)
```

```
   id  Code
0   a    A1
1   a    A2
2   a    A3
3   b    B1
4   b    B2
5   b    B3
```

But the output needs to be like this:

```
d = {'id': ['a', 'b'], 'Code_1': ['A1', 'B1'], 'Code_2':['A2', 'B2'], 'Code_3':['A3', 'B3']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df2)
```

```
   id  Code_1  Code_2  Code_3
0   a    A1      A2      A3
1   b    B1      B2      B3
```

I tried multiple ways. Closest was code i found on a different question that did at least the aggregation part

```
df1.groupby('id')['Code'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

But that gives an output where the different codes are saved into one column as one long string, not saved into multiple columns.

```
  id      Code
0  a  A1 A2 A3
1  b  B1 B2 B3
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the `Code` column of the grouped dataframe on the seperator  and pass a optional parameter `expand=True` which expands the splitted strings into multiple columns this creates a new dataframe `df_s`. Then using [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) you can add the prefix `Code_` to the columns of dataframe `df_s`. Finally using `pd.concat` you can concat the `df_g["id"]` and `df_s` together.

Use:

```
df_g = df1.groupby('id')['Code'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()

df_s = df_g["Code"].str.split(' ', expand=True)
df_s.columns = df_s.columns + 1
df_s =  df_s.add_prefix("Code_")

result = pd.concat([df_g["id"], df_s], axis=1) 
print(result)
```

This prints:

```
 id Code_1 Code_2 Code_3
0  a     A1     A2     A3
1  b     B1     B2     B3
```